# Unable to load DLL 'tesseract.dll' in C#

Tags: c#, dll, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to follow these steps in using this OCR http://tesseract.patagames.com/help/html/baa0aa10-7805-4ae6-b6e9-9df777c4678c.htm

I encountered an unhandled exception saying

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in Patagames.Ocr.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'tesseract.dll': The specified module could not be found. Please make sure that you copy it to the application folder. Alternatively, you can specify the full path to the tesseract.dll file using specificPath parameter in the TessBaseAPICreate method

so I followed some instructions to specify the full path but it is still not working.

```
OcrApi.PathToEngine = @"d:\MyApp\tesseract.dll";
using (var api = OcrApi.Create())
{
    api.Init();
}
```

Is there any other way to make this work?

Comment: Can you post the *exact* error message please.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in Patagames.Ocr.dll

Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'tesseract.dll': The specified module could not be found.  Please make sure that you copy it to the application folder.  Alternatively, you can specify the full path to the tesseract.dll file using specificPath parameter in the TessBaseAPICreate method

Comment: Is your application 32-bit, 64-bit, or AnyCPU? Are you sure you've matched the correct DLL?

Comment: It is clear - Path d:\MyApp\tesseract.dll is not valid. Copy tesseract.dll to bin folder and change OcrApi.PathToEngine to = @"tesseract.dll";

Comment: Yes my pc is 64-bit and Im sure I've used the 64-bit DLL

Comment: Is tesseract.dll a .Net DLL or is it a 'traditional DLL'? If it is the latter, have you tried running DEPENDS.EXE against the DLL to see whether some of its dependencies are not missing.

Comment: @goodeinstein it only needs to be in bin directory if it is a .Net DLL.

Comment: @Übercoder It is a .Net DLL and it is already located in the bin directory. ..\MyApp\bin\Debug\x64\tesseract.dll but it still ain't working

Comment: Try  if (!File.Exist(@"d:\MyApp\tesseract.dll")) OcrApi.PathToEngine = @"d:\MyApp\tesseract.dll";

Comment: @goodeinstein I tried doing that but it still returns the same error.

Answer (score 2):

From doc:

In some cases, library initializer can not find tesseract.dll library to load. A typical example of this situation is a Web application. Web apps is running in a IIS working directory, unlike the classical apps. As a consequence, standard LoadLibrary function can not find the dll during loading process.

In this case, you must explicitly specify the full path to the tesseract.dll file through this property.

The initialization algorithm is as follows:

- Attempting to load dll from the path which received through PathToEngine property.
- Attempting to load dll from x64 or x86 folder.Needed folder automatically detected by based the process compilation mode and operating system.
- Attempting to load dll from the working directory of the process which call initialization.
- Attempting to load dll from the same directory where placed assembly which call initialization.
  Otherwise, initialization error.

http://tesseract.patagames.com/help/html/P_Patagames_Ocr_OcrApi_PathToEngine.htm

Answer (score 1):

By using this method it works for me :

```
OcrApi.PathToEngine = @"d:\MyApp\tesseract.dll";
```

But main problem is that before build `copy` this folders `(tessdata, x64, x86 files)` into Your Project root directory  (Right click on root project > open folder with window explorer) and make sure you have added `Patagames.Ocr` reference in your project then go to `\bin\Debug\` and `paste` here and you are DONE.

Run the project and see the Magic :)